# Error: SHA256 mismatch with brew install

Tags: macos, homebrew

I tried to install an application with homebrew:

```
$ brew install poppler
```

And then towards the end of the installation, I notice the following error:

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/GNOME/gobject-introspection/commit/4a724ac699f0c34fba2fb452cfadea11540325e8.patch
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 047c350bad2d222f1037c3ce1889444ebc1095df76120188037c4eb2900848c4
Actual: 928403cf8eb092c664791f5e08cff1199ac9e945d8d5fd21c455c688efbc6dd5
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gobject-introspection--patch-047c350bad2d222f1037c3ce1889444ebc1095df76120188037c4eb2900848c4.patch
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

What happened here? Dos this error prevent the application from completing installation?

Comment: It's likely the download was interupted, you should try removing the file per the instructions and downloading again..

Comment: You might also try brew doctor if you have further issues or check the git hub issues page for that project.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can we presume you removed the file indicated and then tried again and receive the same error?

Comment: @bmike this file /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gobject-introspection--patch-047c350bad2d222f1037c3ce1889444ebc1095df76120188037c4eb2900848c4.patc does not even exist.

Comment: Are you just running `brew install poppler`? Which version of macOS and brew do you have installed? If it's downloading the patch that suggests it's trying to compile poppler. By default brew should just be trying to download the pre-compiled binary gobject-introspection-1.54.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz and install that.

Comment: Also brew's cache really shouldn't be in `/Library/Caches`. Are you running `brew` with `sudo`? The developers really recommend against doing that. https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with brew install.

Try running `rm ${file_above} && brew install poppler`

Note: file_above is not an actually defined variable (at least not in bash) with only the above command. Given the original post, for example, `${file_above}` should be replaced with (or otherwise defined first):

`/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gobject-introspection--patch-047c350bad2d222f1037c3ce1889444ebc1095df76120188037c4eb2900848c4.patch`

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall and reinstall the homebrew using following scripts which can be found here
https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew
Then run following commands in the following sequence

1. brew cleanup
2. brew upgrade
3. brew install poppler

Comment: It fixed things when I only ran the commands - **I didn't need to uninstall/reinstall brew**.